# Demoing data science work

Tags: visualization

To data scientists who use python for development, how do you demo your work?

I used to demo my work in Shiny as my developments was mainly in R. Now I develop 99% in Python but not sure of the best way to demo work (predictive modelling, data analytics side, pattern detection,..etc)?

Currently I use Dash, but the amount if time I spend on html and css makes it less appealing.

Comment: Demo-ing to other data scientists, or to a wider audience?

Comment: @NeilSlater both

Comment: Those two would be 2 different perspectives, if wider audience they might not be interested in your techniques they would like to know more about the impact but Data Scientists would be interested in how you implemented, architectures etc. So I think keep them separate would be suggestible.

Comment: @Toros91 yes, I agree. If I get a tool that can be adapted to accommodate both, that would be the best case scenario. If not, the emphasis here would be on the wider audience.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Jupyter notebook. Write good descriptions in Markdown between blocks of code. Here are some examples showing machine learning in Python:

https://github.com/ogrisel/notebooks

https://github.com/ogrisel/notebooks/blob/master/Labeled%20Faces%20in%20the%20Wild%20recognition.ipynb

Comment: But how can I make it interactive like Shiny for example.

Comment: Who said you can't make it interactive? https://blog.dominodatalab.com/interactive-dashboards-in-jupyter/